# How to resolve "Lodash chain sequences are not supported by babel-plugin-lodash"

Tags: javascript, babeljs, lodash

I am using Lodash chain and am running into the above issue when building my service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue comes from babel-plugin-lodash not supporting lodash chains.

To solve the issue, you must use lodash's flow operator instead.

Here is an example:

```
// using chain
const result = _.chain(array)
  .map(fn1)
  .filter(fn2)
  .value();

// using flow
const result = _.flow([
  arr => _.map(arr, fn1),
  arr => _.filter(arr, fn2)
])(array);
```